# Pixel Ruler tool for windows

Tags: windows, pixel-graphics

I am looking for free, pixel ruler software (for Windows, installer or portable or anything runnable on Windows. No browsers plugin
, just an application.) It needs to measure webpage components' width and height in pixels on my screen. I'm currently using Mioplanet's pixel ruler but it seems like it was stopped being supported and not good enough for me because it doesn't have setting or hot key feature. I have to go to the Start menu every time. Can somebody please advice me?

Comment: Please add some more detail to your question. What specific features do you want/need? What is it about Mioplanet Pixel Ruler that makes it not good enough for you? The more information that you can provide, the better the recommendation that we can give you.

Comment: A program, or browser extension?  Chrome extension?

Comment: Many browsers (Chrome, IE, Firefox) can display the size of an element in their inspector tools

Comment: Why the downvote? Does my question being unclear? Didn't I describe anything I want? Or downvote because there are several plugin available for browsers and I'm asking for windows application?

Comment: Super User has a [virtually identical question](https://superuser.com/questions/19241/good-on-screen-ruler-application-for-windows) (which would have been great to migrate here). That question is older but does have answers with some viable options not mentioned (yet) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [PicPick](http://www.picpick.org),
It has lots of useful tools,  including a couple different ways to measure pixels, one of them being an easy to use pixel ruler

- Its free
- Avaliable for Windows
- Easy to use
- Nice UI
- it's an Application, not a browser plug-in
- Also available as a portable app
- I'm pretty sure it has a hot key feature (although, I'm not certain)

Comment: Accepted this answer because this pixel ruler have hot key and Magnifier!! Thanks for suggesting amazing app.

Comment: Serious question: does this answer still hold true now in 2016, about a year and a half later?

Comment: @SarahofGaia yes,  still highly recommend the program. Very useful for almost any kind designing done on a computer

Comment: @hhaslam11 I just went to the site to check it out and it has a very diverse set of functions. All I want is a ruler, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ruler](http://ruler.codeplex.com/)

- free
- runs on Windows
- very simple to use - just open and measure!
- tooltip (activate by right clicking ruler) to show width and height of ruler in pixels
- vertical / horizontal (choose by right clicking ruler)
- change opacity by right clicking
- portable (single .exe)

[image]

Comment: simple and awesome! Thanks. Even though it doesn't have a hot key function, it has option to disable 'always on top'.

Comment: I'm also happy with this little app, it's now found on github: https://github.com/andrijac/ruler

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JR Screen Ruler Pro](http://www.spadixbd.com/freetools/jruler.htm) (lite and pro version are in the zipped folder; both are free):

- free
- runs on Windows
- easy to use - just open and measure!
- XY coordinates of cursor (when hovering over ruler)
- vertical / horizontal (choose by right clicking ruler)
- rotate (by right clicking)
- change transparency by right clicking
- can change colors
- portable (single .exe)
- pixels, inches, centimetres, picas

[image]

I've been using it for a few months now (design work), it works great for me!

Comment: Great! don't even have to rotate to get height.